# Other Emacs profile unable to load directory path

Tags: doom, org-roam, sqlite

I used to use vanilla emacs and am trying out Doom emacs in a separate chemacs profile where my config files are under ~/.doom.d/ and my doom files are under ~/.emacs.doom.d/

I am trying to use the org-roam package but unfortunately my Doom Emacs profile is unable to detect the sqlite.exe executible file in the ~/sqlite/ directory. My vanilla Emacs configuration is able to detect it and they both have similar configuration files `(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/sqlite")`.

So far I've tried:

- Making sure that ~/sqlite goes to the same directory by evaluating (expand-file-name ~/sqlite) to make sure it points to the correct directory
- Trying

```
(setq exec-path '(
                  "~/sqlite"
                  ))
```

I also ran `bin/doom sync` and `bin/doom env` afterwards

I'm on windows for context.